# Why am I being asked to download "Push" on any adsense based website?

Tags: web-development, google-adsense, cross-browser, bugs

I regularly use Opera web browser to browse websites and today, I just tested my website after installing ads at with the size 300x250 pixels, and sometimes a download box appears asking me to download a temporary file which I believe is called "push". I cancel the download and my website loads normally.

My site must not prompt users to download a file unless they specifically select the option to download the image from the site.

I never experience this issue when I have no ads on my site.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, what can I do on my end to prevent my guests from being asked to download a useless file? do I have to not use 300x250 pixel ads on my site anymore? or should I just simply send negative feedback to google and/or its partners?

Comment: I am sure it is not the ad size but the ad type. I do not know what this *push* is, however, when I am other sites (using Chrome) some video ads ask me to install something I do not have. I have flash updated and so most ads work just fine. But some sites use these annoying video ads that chew up my CPU and sometimes ask me to download something. It could be something along the same lines but not necessarily video like what I see.

Comment: you might have nailed it.

Comment: Should I get a crowbar and un-nail it?? ;-) I have cr@p-load of them...

Comment: Any "advert" that prompts you to download anything - particularly unsolicited - sounds malicious!? I don't think any kind of legitimate "push" advertising should prompt you to download something - unless it's "broken"? What browser are you using?

Comment: Opera 11.62 build 1347 for linux. Yes I still use an older computer.

Comment: I just wonder... is it possible that these adverts are being served with a (newer?) Content-Type that your browser does not understand?! If this was the case then usual browser behaviour is to prompt to download - since it doesn't know what else to do with it. (?)

Answer (score 2):

This is a glitch with the MIME types on the AdSense servers which occurred some time ago. Last time I spoke to Google about it I was told that it was being fixed but it still comes up on occasion. When this happens the only real solution is to disable adsense for a few days to give Google a chance to patch the AdSense servers and fix the issue, unfortunately not much else you can do about it.